# iPad - Different Images in Launch Storyboard for iPad in Landscape & Portrait Mode

Tags: ios, ipad, uistoryboard, launch

I have an iPad app that has a different layout depending on its orientation.
I want a different startup image depending on whether the iPad is in Portrait or Landscape orientation.

The app is enabled for multi-tasking, so uses a Launch Storyboard.

I know I can vary the image depending on the traits, but when in full screen mode, the iPad class sizes width & height are **Regular** in both Landscape and Portrait mode.

So is it possible to have different startup images in the above scenario ?

Comment: do you mean in Portrait orientation setup a image, and in Landscape orientation use anther different image?

Comment: I do not understand " but when in full screen mode, the iPad class sizes width & height are Regular in both Landscape and Portrait mode." this  line, what do you mean?

Comment: Yes I want to setup different splash screen pictures when using a Luanch Screen.

When varying traits in a storyboard, 
clicking on the iPad in Full Screen Portrait Mode its size classes are Regular for both Width and Height.
Clicking on the iPad in Full Screen Landscape Mode in the storyboard also shows the size classes as Regular for both Width & Height.

So it didnt seem possible to have a different picture for the 2 orientations as the class sizes are the same.

Comment: Hey @philB did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Sorry No. We ended up changing to a splash screen that was independent of the screen orientation.